# How to center vertically the text within a multiple div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying hard for the past hours to switch from the left column to the right one. I mean, I'm trying to center vertically the text div inside the grey div.

I would love to get some of your help. I've read a lot of tutorials and forum answer but didn't get the expected result yet.

Any advice is more than welcome :)

[image: Present problem and expected result]
HTML Code :

```css
.box-key-message{
    height: 240px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.box-key-message div {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.box-key-message span {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:16px;
    color: #D5420F;
}
```

```html
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1">
    <div class="box-key-message">
    <div>
      <span> Gratuit</span>
      <br /><br />
        Notre service, qui vous permet d’accéder à des centaines d’étudiants, est complètement gratuit pour vous.
      <br /><br />
        Vous ne rémunérez que l’étudiant. Un acompte de 15% vous sera demandé au moment de la mise en relation. Le reste sera payé une fois tous les succès de votre mission atteints !
    </div>
    </div>

    <br /><br />

    <div class="box-key-message">
    <div>
    <span>Simple et Rapide</span>
      <br /><br />
    Remplissez cette page en 5 minutes pour publier une mission à tous nos étudiants.
      <br /><br />
    Vous recevrez alors le CV des étudiants intéressés par votre mission. Une fois l’étudiant sélectionné, la mission commence.
    </div>
    </div>
    <br /><br />

    <div class="box-key-message">
    <div>
    <span>Sans engagement</span>
      <br /><br />
    Les étudiants des Grandes Ecoles qui vous répondent sont qualifiés, motivés, disponibles et réactifs.
      <br /><br />
    Si malgré tout aucun profil ne vous correspond, vous n’avez aucune obligation de recruter un étudiant et poster la mission aura été gratuit.
    </div>
    </div>
    <br /><br />

    <div class="box-key-message">
    <div>
    <span>Et pour payer l’étudiant ?</span>
      <br /><br />
    L’étudiant vous facturera la prestation en direct à la fin de la mission.
    </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Don't use break tags for spacing, that's what margins, padding and general correct use of elements is for. you obviously should have headings and paragraphs there...use the **correct elements**.

Comment: I forgot to tell that I've learnt CSS and Bootstrap last week. Therefore, my code isn't really nice yet... But I'll remove the break tags, thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `display: table; table-layout: fixed;` for the parent div and `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` for every child. See how it works below. You probably also will need to specify `width: 100%` to both of them.

```css
.box-key-message{
    height: 240px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.box-key-message div {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
width: 100%;
}

.box-key-message span {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:16px;
    color: #D5420F;
}
```

```html
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1">
    <div class="box-key-message">
    <div>
      <span> Gratuit</span>
      <br /><br />
        Notre service, qui vous permet d’accéder à des centaines d’étudiants, est complètement gratuit pour vous.
      <br /><br />
        Vous ne rémunérez que l’étudiant. Un acompte de 15% vous sera demandé au moment de la mise en relation. Le reste sera payé une fois tous les succès de votre mission atteints !
    </div>
    </div>

    <br /><br />

    <div class="box-key-message">
    <div>
    <span>Simple et Rapide</span>
      <br /><br />
    Remplissez cette page en 5 minutes pour publier une mission à tous nos étudiants.
      <br /><br />
    Vous recevrez alors le CV des étudiants intéressés par votre mission. Une fois l’étudiant sélectionné, la mission commence.
    </div>
    </div>
    <br /><br />

    <div class="box-key-message">
    <div>
    <span>Sans engagement</span>
      <br /><br />
    Les étudiants des Grandes Ecoles qui vous répondent sont qualifiés, motivés, disponibles et réactifs.
      <br /><br />
    Si malgré tout aucun profil ne vous correspond, vous n’avez aucune obligation de recruter un étudiant et poster la mission aura été gratuit.
    </div>
    </div>
    <br /><br />

    <div class="box-key-message">
    <div>
    <span>Et pour payer l’étudiant ?</span>
      <br /><br />
    L’étudiant vous facturera la prestation en direct à la fin de la mission.
    </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @simon ! It's done, finally ! I don't understand why using a table for this purpose yet but I'll dig into it :)

Comment: this is just a simple CSS hack - tables support vertical centering :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the inner div as a table-cell, then vertical-align works on it.

I also improved your HTML, instead of using two line breaks, it's better to use paragraphs or margin.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1">
    <div class="box-key-message">
        <div>
            <span> Gratuit</span>
            <p>Notre service, qui vous permet d’accéder à des centaines d’étudiants, est complètement gratuit pour vous.</p>
            <p>Vous ne rémunérez que l’étudiant. Un acompte de 15% vous sera demandé au moment de la mise en relation. Le reste sera payé une fois tous les succès de votre mission atteints !</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-key-message">
        <div>
            <span>Simple et Rapide</span>
            <p>Remplissez cette page en 5 minutes pour publier une mission à tous nos étudiants.</p>
            <p>Vous recevrez alors le CV des étudiants intéressés par votre mission. Une fois l’étudiant sélectionné, la mission commence.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-key-message">
        <div>
            <span>Sans engagement</span>
            <p>Les étudiants des Grandes Ecoles qui vous répondent sont qualifiés, motivés, disponibles et réactifs.</p>
            <p>Si malgré tout aucun profil ne vous correspond, vous n’avez aucune obligation de recruter un étudiant et poster la mission aura été gratuit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-key-message">
        <div>
            <span>Et pour payer l’étudiant ?</span>
            <p>L’étudiant vous facturera la prestation en direct à la fin de la mission.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.box-key-message {
    height: 240px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    display: table;
}
.box-key-message div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
}
.box-key-message span {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:16px;
    color: #D5420F;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yg8Lm5n7/1/)

Comment: dude you use vertical-align:middle; on both divs parent and children, It seems you dont know how it is working, so lets put it on both div. As explanation it should be on children div because .box-key-message div is the one should be centered vertically so there is no point to add this to parent.

Comment: @SzymonDziewoński: honest mistake, and yes, I always forget on which element I should apply it. Fixed it.

Comment: Thank you @LinkinTED for your help on my HTML ! I see it as a nice Bonus. I'll remember it !

Comment: @LinkinTED no problem, I just tryin to help :) good job with helping

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: table; width:100%;` on `.box-key-message`, and `display: table-cell` on the div within it in.  You want to use the table css hack because tables support `vertical-align: middle` while regular divs do not.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1">
        <div class="box-key-message">
            <div>
                <p><strong> Gratuit</strong></p>
                <p>Notre service, qui vous permet d’accéder à des centaines d’étudiants, est complètement gratuit pour vous.</p>
                <p>Vous ne rémunérez que l’étudiant. Un acompte de 15% vous sera demandé au moment de la mise en relation. Le reste sera payé une fois tous les succès de votre mission atteints !</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box-key-message">
            <div>
                <p><strong>Simple et Rapide</strong></p>
                <p>Remplissez cette page en 5 minutes pour publier une mission à tous nos étudiants.</p>
                <p>Vous recevrez alors le CV des étudiants intéressés par votre mission. Une fois l’étudiant sélectionné, la mission commence.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="box-key-message">
        <div>
            <p><strong>Sans engagement</strong></p>
            <p>Les étudiants des Grandes Ecoles qui vous répondent sont qualifiés, motivés, disponibles et réactifs.</p>
            <p>Si malgré tout aucun profil ne vous correspond, vous n’avez aucune obligation de recruter un étudiant et poster la mission aura été gratuit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box-key-message">
        <div>
            <p><strong>Et pour payer l’étudiant ?</strong></p>
            <p>L’étudiant vous facturera la prestation en direct à la fin de la mission.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box-key-message{
        height: 240px;
        display:table;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;    
        width: 100%;
}

.box-key-message div {
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: justify;
}

.box-key-message strong {
        font-size:16px;
        color: #D5420F;
}
```

As a sidenote, you overused break tags a little too much.  You can get the spacing you want for the content inside the `.box-key-message` divs by using paragraph tags around your content. To separate out the box-key-message blocks so they won't touch each other, you can add a `margin-bottom: 20px;` (or whatever spacing you prefer) to .box-key-message in your css.

See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/sfrisk/pen/b6e976f2850a21b11e71d55267f56f39/) for an example.